# Apache Shiro authentication customization

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, spring-security, shiro

How can I customize authentication logic in Apache Shiro? In Spring Security I write my custom logic inside the "authenticate()" method in AuthenticationManager:

`public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) { ... }`

Is there a way to do the same in Apache Shiro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are overviews of Shiro's [authentication sequence](https://shiro.apache.org/authentication.html#Authentication-AuthenticationSequence) and [customizable realm authentication](https://shiro.apache.org/realm.html#Realm-RealmAuthentication).

Depending on what you want to do, your own implementation of a [`CredentialsMatcher`](https://shiro.apache.org/realm.html#Realm-CredentialsMatching) could be the hook you're looking for? A detailed answer on which parts you need to customize really depends on your actual authentication scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

I have a web application, login url: /ls?action=login
I've read that I must call login() method on SecurityUtils.getSubject() object. I cannot understand how to pass username and password to login() method. Shall I call this login() method inside Servlet and then redirect to a secured location?

Comment: If all you want to do is call the `login()` method with a username/pwd, simply construct a `new UsernamePasswordToken(username, password)` and pass it as a parameter to `login()`, as described [here](https://shiro.apache.org/authentication.html#Authentication-Authenticating%7B%7BSubjects%7D%7D)

Comment: That's what I don't know how to do. How to override .login() method? Actually I want to implement my own logic inside .login() method. I read about realms - but I am not sure which realm to choose.

Comment: Have you looked at `ActiveDirectoryRealm`, `CasRealm`, `JdbcRealm`, `JndiLdapRealm`, `PropertiesRealm`, `SimpleAccountRealm`, or `TextConfigurationRealm` to determine which would make a good starting point for whatever you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks @greenSocksRock. Yes the realm did the job :)